# explicit formula for position of lowest bit of binary representation of number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, binary, binary-operations

Given some positive integer $x>0$, let $h(x)$ be the number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of $x$.

For Example, if $x = 12$ then the binary representation of $x$ is $1100_{2}$ and $h(x) = 2$

Is there a known **explicit formula** for $h(x)$?

Thank you all for you responses especially [ganeshie8](/questions/tagged/ganeshie8)

I wanted to add a few more properties of $h(x)$

$$
  h(2m+1) = 0 \hspace{5mm}\forall m \geq 0\\
  h(2^m x) = m + h(x) \hspace{16mm}
$$

Comment: $h(x)$ is the highest exponent of $2$ that divides the given number

Comment: If you're allowed to use bitwise and/not operators, you may try:  `h(x) = log_2(x & ( ~(x - 1)))`

Comment: Is there a way to write $h(x)$ without using any binary operators?

Comment: pj5772 I can't think of any other way. I know using bitwise operators is cheating haha

Comment: I think it is an interesting question. $h(x)$ should have some very interesting properties. $h(2x) = h(x) + 1$, and $h(2m+1) = 0$ for all positive integer $m$

Comment: $h(2^kx) = h(x)+k$

Comment: To my knowledge it's impossible to find an explicit formula for $h(x)$ in terms of regular functions like roots logs etc. Do let me know if you find any... Good luck!:)

Comment: @ganeshie8 What do you mean "the highest exponent"? Do you mean $x \mid 2^{h(x)}$? If so, you're right, it's impossible to find such explicit formula, as it is equivalent to factoring.

Comment: @QuoteDave They mean that $h(x)$ is the largest $n$ such that $2^n|x$.

Comment: @Jam Yeah, that's what I thought. Ok.

Comment: In Pari/GP it is called "valuation": `? valuation(12,2)` then the answer is`2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $h(x)$ is the greatest $n$ such that $2^n$ divides $x$. This implies your observation that odd $x$ have $h(x)=0$ but also some semblance of periodicity in $h(x)$. Every second $h(x)$ is at least $1$, every fourth $h(x)$ is at least $2$ and so on. This is simply tally of how many twos divide $x$.

With this in mind, we can look for a function that varies periodically, according to the divisibility of its input. For example, we can choose the modulo operator, $\operatorname{mod}(x, y)$, which is the remainder of the Euclidean division of $x$ by $y$.

$\operatorname{mod}(x, y)$ rises from $0$ to a maximum of $(y-1)$. We can normalise it by $(y-1)$ and then take the floor of that, which gives us $1$ for every $y$'th number and $0$ otherwise. For example, $\left\lfloor\frac{\operatorname{mod}(x, 4)}{4-1}\right\rfloor$ is $1$ at every fourth integer and $0$ otherwise. The peak of the mod function is at $(y-1)$, so we then translate the previous function $1$ unit to the right so all $1$s are at multiples of $y$. Therefore $\left\lfloor\frac{\operatorname{mod}(x-1, y)}{y-1}\right\rfloor$ is the indicator of when $x$ is divisible by $y$. Summing these terms, when $y$ are different powers of two, gives a tally for the number of powers of two that divide $x$.

Hence, we have the explicit formula $$h(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{\operatorname{mod}(x-1, 2^n)}{2^n-1}\right\rfloor$$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/osiqmhxndi

You can also express the floor and modulo operators as series of sinusoids if you want a series composed solely of elementary functions.

---

**Edit:** Revisiting this, we can consider each $\left\lfloor\frac{\operatorname{mod}(x-1, y)}{y-1}\right\rfloor$ summand as a piecewise function $f_k(x)=\begin{cases}1,&0\leq x<1\\0,&1\leq x<2^k\end{cases}$, which is periodic on $\mathbb{R}$ with period $2^k$. The functions $f_k$ can be made into Fourier series by partitioning the relevant integrals over intervals according to the piecewise function and then solving them with elementary calculus. Lastly, we sum $f_k(x)$ over $k$, combine all $a_0$ terms of the Fourier series into the geometric series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}=1$ and simplify with the angle sum formula for sine. This gives us the neat double series of elementary summands:

$$h(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(cx\right)+\sin\left(c\left(1-x\right)\right)}{\pi n}$$

where $c=\frac{\pi n}{2^{k-1}}$. This numerically agrees with the previous formula. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5hayvzzwil

Comment: Very nice idea. I just tried it with sums of sine-functions (of even powers of it) but it was too much fiddling. This sum-of-mod function looks much clearer. Maybe, someone with experience in Fourier-analysis might give it in half a minute, but I'm without that experience...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Me too, it's very fiddly. The most challenging part is the sums *within* sines. Ideally we'd be able to expand those terms.

Comment: that's why I tried to use even powers of sin(x), for instance $\sin(\pi x)^{20}$ or so: then the curve approximates its shape towards the spiky form of the floor(modulo())-construction that you've introduced.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, and explanation. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms FWIW I revisited the question and found a (double) series.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested by Gottfried.

In math, there is the [$2$-adic valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) ... this $h$ is the reciprocal of it.
$$
\nu_2(12) = \frac{1}{2}
$$
And in general $\nu_2(2^k m) = 2^{-k}$ if $m$ is odd.

Comment: Nice, I will look more into 2-adic valuation.